# Chaining xwininfo and imagemagick in a single alias command?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to alias a chain of

```
xwininfo | grep "Window id" | awk -F ' ' '{print $4}'
```

with

```
import -window <SOMETHING> <SOMETHING2>
```

such that I can run that alias command, have it let me click on a window and create a screenshot with a file name that is the argument of the aliased command. It seems like `SOMETHING` might be able to be `$_` and `SOMETHING2` might be `$2` but I can't get any combination of that and pipes to work.

Comment: I think the default separator in `awk` is a space anyway, so `-F ' '` is probably redundant. Nor do you need `grep` since `awk` can search just as well `awk '/Window id/{print $4}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you should not use aliases but rather functions:

```
function foo { 
   win_id=$(xwininfo | grep "Window id" | awk -F ' ' '{print $4}')
   import -window $win_id $1
}
```

This you can then use as:

```
$ foo window.jpg
```

which looks a bit similar to an alias but is really not.

Comment: You might also be interested in just using `gnome-screenshot -i` if you use gnome.